# C++20 Generic Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20

I am learning templates right now and after following a tutorial came up with the following solution for computing basically a dot-product of two tuples:

```
template<typename Tup, size_t ix>
double get_double(Tup const &tup) {
   return static_cast<double>(std::get<ix>(tup));
}

template<typename Tup1, typename Tup2, size_t... Ix>
double euclidean_distance(Tup1 const &tup1, Tup2 const &tup2, std::index_sequence<Ix...>)
{
    return ((get_double<Tup1,Ix>(tup1) * get_double<Tup2,Ix>(tup2)) + ...);
}
```

This seems pretty decent to me, but I am trying to move the **get_double** function as a "generic lambda" into the **euclidean_distance** function. I've been trying various variations of the code below for the last hour but am still ending up with a wall of errors, the first one listed below (supposedly everything else is cascading from it). Is there a way to do this with generic lambda's or are they less powerful than normal templates? I am compiling with -std=c++20.

```
template<typename Tup1, typename Tup2, size_t... Ix>
double euclidean_distance(Tup1 const &tup1, Tup2 const &tup2, std::index_sequence<Ix...>)
{
   auto get_double = []<typename Tup, size_t ix>(Tup const& tup) {
       return static_cast<double>(std::get<ix>(tup));
   };

   return ((get_double<Tup1,Ix>(tup1) * get_double<Tup2,Ix>(tup2)) + ...);
}
```

> recent.cpp: In function ‘double euclidean_distance(const Tup1&, const Tup2&, std::index_sequence<_Idx ...>)’:
> recent.cpp:11:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
> 11 |     return ((get_double<Tup1,Ix>(tup1) * get_double<Tup2,Ix>(tup2)) + ...);
> |                             ^

Comment: fixed. formatting issue was hiding the first template<...> line